# A question about complemented subspaces of Banach spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $E$ be a Banach space and $F$ a complemented subspace of $E$. Prove that if $E= F \oplus M$ and $E=F \oplus N$, then $M$ is isomorphic to $N$.

My attempt:

First we need the lemma:

(Isomorphism Theorem): If $E$ and $F$ are Banach spaces and $T \in \mathcal{L}(E,F)$ and $T(E)$ is closed in $F$, then $T(E)$ is isomorphic to $\frac{E}{Ker(T)}$

Back to the problem:

Since $F$ is complemented subspace of the Banach space $E$ there exists a projection $P:E \rightarrow E$ whose image $P(E)$ is $F$, for the same reason $F$ is a closed subspace of the Banach space $E$ and it is itself a Banach space, applying the Isomorphism Theorem we can conclude that $F$ is isomorphic to $\frac{E}{kerP}$.

My next objetive is show that both $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic to $KerP$ and then isomorphic to each other, but I don't know how to do this and I need help.

Comment: Surely you want to show that $M \approx E / F \approx N$?

Comment: Yes, the book says $M$ isomorphic to $N$, so one strategy is to show that both $M$ and $N$ are isomorphic to $E/F$ ?

Comment: I'm saying, maybe you want different projections. Instead of projecting onto $F$, try two different projections onto $M$ and $N$ with $F$ as the kernel.

Answer (score 1):

$\because E=F \bigoplus M,\therefore$ M isomorphic to E/F by the theorem,so do N.